# UITableView Displaying Static Content

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am making a settings screen for my iPhone app. The settings screen using UITableView static cells. I am using Storyboards and designer to drag and drop elements in the UITableViewCells. The problem I am facing is that I have lots of settings and in Storyboard I can only see the part of the UITableView (The 320XHeight of the iPhone). What if I want to drag and drop elements on the screen which are not currently visible since the UITableView is not scrolled to that position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by changing the interface orientation of the UITableViewController to "FreeForm".

This will then allow you to drag the edges of the UITableViewController to change its size.

You can also use the scrolly wheel (or two finger drag) to scroll the content of the table view to bring the other cells into view.

Comment: Nice! I did not knew about the two finder drag. This will make this much easier! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

While editing the tableview just make the height of the UIView and TableView in the storyboard > height of the device.

After you are done editing you can put it back to the original size.